# Is Event-Driven Programming possible using Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an event that I want to take an action off of when it happens. This event is being processed by Logstash and pushed to Elastic Search.

I see in the [docs for Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline.html#_filters) that there are `Filters` and `Outputs`. I thought the Filter might have been what I was after, but looking closer at the docs it does not seem to have the functionality to push data to an endpoint/API: `Filters are intermediary processing devices in the Logstash pipeline. You can combine filters with conditionals to perform an action on an event if it meets certain criteria.`

Is it possible to take an action when the event is being processed by Logstash 7.4? Or do I need to wait to take some type of action until I do some polling-based queries for the event in ElasticSearch?

Comment: are you talking about [http filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-http.html)?

Comment: Since you can have multiple outputs in your configuration, if there's an output that fit the action you want to do, you could add a tag on that specific event, then use logstash [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.4/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) so that the output is only called for that event.